# MySQL Find how many days it needed to get the highest positive progression

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Data set:

```
CREATE TABLE TEMPERATURES (
  CREATED DATE,
  ACTUAL_TEMPERATURE FLOAT
  );

INSERT INTO TEMPERATURES VALUES
('20170101',12.2),
('20170103',10.1),
('20170112',14.2),
('20170115',12.5),
('20170205',20.8),
('20170122',16.7),
('20170123',7.8),
('20170130',12.5),
('20170201',13.7),
('20170302',14.8),
('20170313',11.1),
('20170414',12.0),
('20170525',10.4);
```

and SQL FIDDLE of same: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9b11e

I just want to find how many days it needed to get the highest positive progression ?

The result I would like to have is :

```
20170103 10.1
20170205 20.8
```

Be careful, I don't want to have :

```
20170123 7.8
20170302 14.8
```

I tried many requests and many ways and no succeed.

Is it possible and if yes, how ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't understand. 14.2 to 12.5 seems like a negative progression.

Comment: What do you mean by "highest positive progression"?  And you say you want a number of days, but the sample results have dates.

Comment: @Strawberry You're right, I don't care about the numbers "inside".
The result I need is the biggest positive gap between two numbers.
And the Min has to be before the Max.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  In another word, I would like to have the biggest positive gap. I will use php to calculate the number of days.

Comment: The biggest difference is between ('20170123',7.8) and ('20170205',20.8) - and there are no 'days' in your desired result.

Comment: @Strawberry I would like to have the biggest positive gap. And the date of Min has to be before the date Max. I need SQL to get this result : (20170103, 10.1) & (20170205, 20.8). To calculate the number of days, I will use PHP.

Comment: Yes. The biggest positive gap is between the values I've identified above.

Comment: @Strawberry You're right, I made a mistake in my datas, SORRY. The good SQLfiddle is : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2385d8/1 The result I need remains : (20170103, 10.1) & (20170205, 20.8)

Comment: I still see no 'days' in your desired result. This means that the thing that you say you want, and the thing you show us you want, are different. It's very confusing.

Comment: @Strawberry Sorry for my bad english. Forget days. I would like to have the biggest positive gap. And the date of Min has to be before the date Max. I need SQL to get this result : (20170103, 10.1) & (20170205, 20.8).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description of the problem, I think you want:

```
select grp, min(created), max(created),
       min(actual_temperature), max(actual_temperature)
from (select t.*,
             (@grp := @grp + coalesce(prev_at > actual_temperature, 0)) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   (select t2.actual_temperature
                    from temperatures t2
                    where t2.created < t.created
                    order by t2.created desc
                    limit 1
                   ) as prev_at
            from temperatures t
            order by created
           ) t cross join
           (select @grp := 0) params
      ) t
group by grp
order by max(actual_temperature) - min(actual_temperature) desc
limit 1;
```

This identifies streaks of increasing temperatures.  It then returns the streak with the highest difference between the maximum and minimum.

This is how I interpret your question, although your results do not fully conform to this interpretation.

Comment: Thanks, but is not the result I wanted. I need in one SQL request : 20170103 10.1
and 20170205 20.8 Do you think it's possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a function, something like this (you still need to adjust the edge cases):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION find_progressive(startingDate DATE)
  RETURNS VARCHAR(100) DETERMINISTIC
  BEGIN
    DECLARE risultato int default 0;

    /* current cursor*/
     DECLARE curr_data DATE;
    DECLARE curr_temp FLOAT;    
    /*current best*/
    DECLARE max_temp FLOAT;
    DECLARE min_temp FLOAT;    
    DECLARE max_created DATE;
    DECLARE min_created DATE;        
     /* absolute best*/
    DECLARE best_max_created DATE;
    DECLARE best_min_created DATE;
    DECLARE best_max_temp FLOAT;
    DECLARE best_min_temp FLOAT;

    DECLARE temptemp FLOAT;
    DECLARE tempcreated DATE;

    DECLARE done INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE cursore_temperature CURSOR FOR
      SELECT
        created,
        ACTUAL_TEMPERATURE
      FROM temperatures
      WHERE created > startingDate
      ORDER BY created;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER
    FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

       SELECT
        created,
        ACTUAL_TEMPERATURE
        INTO
        min_created,
        min_temp
      FROM temperatures
      ORDER BY created
        LIMIT 1;          

        SELECT
        created,
        ACTUAL_TEMPERATURE
        INTO
        max_created,
        max_temp
      FROM temperatures
      WHERE created > min_created
      ORDER BY created
        LIMIT 1;

        IF min_temp > max_temp
        THEN          
          set temptemp = min_temp;
          set tempcreated =max_created;
          set min_temp = max_temp;
          set min_created = max_created;
          set max_temp = temptemp;
          set max_created = tempcreated;
        END IF;

        set best_max_temp = max_temp;
        set best_min_temp = min_temp;
        set best_max_created = max_created;
        set best_min_created = min_created;

     OPEN cursore_temperature;

    read_loop: LOOP

      FETCH cursore_temperature
      INTO curr_data, curr_temp;

      IF done = 1 
      THEN
        LEAVE read_loop;
      END IF;           

        IF curr_temp < min_temp
        THEN                
            IF (max_temp - min_temp) > ( best_max_temp - best_min_temp)
            THEN
              set best_max_temp = max_temp;
              set best_max_created = max_created;
              set best_min_temp = min_temp;
              set best_min_created = min_created;
            END IF;

          set min_temp = curr_temp;
          set min_created = curr_data;
          set max_temp = curr_temp;     
          set max_created = curr_data;                    
        END IF;

        IF curr_temp > max_temp
        THEN
          set max_temp = curr_temp;
          set max_created = curr_data;
        END IF;

    END LOOP;

    CLOSE cursore_temperature;
    RETURN CONCAT_WS(' | ', best_min_created, best_min_temp, best_max_created, best_max_temp);
  END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

and you call it like

```
select find_progressive('2017-01-03');
```

and the result is `2017-01-03 | 10.1 | 2017-02-05 | 20.8`

anyway I guess it is not the best talking about optimization.

Comment: Amazing ! thank you very much for your BIG help !!! Then I understand  there is no possibility without stored function. Isn't it ?

Comment: Hi, I hope it will work for you (in case please upvote the answer :-)
I can´t think to something else but a function. I tried to think to a query but...

Comment: OK Thanks. I already tried to upvote you, but stackoverflow doesn't let me : "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."